# Android TextInputLayout Styling programmatically

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that has full UI customization. If you look at  a `EditText` wrapped in an `TextInputLayout`, the `EditText`'s default text hint color and line color are the same as the color `textPrimaryColor` defined in styles. When the `EditText` receives focus however, the line becomes the color of the `accent` defined in styles, the hint goes through the floating hint animation and changes to the `accent` color. It's pretty easy to do with `styles.xml` and `themes.xml`, however, I can't quite get it programmatically.

The current method I have set up is this:

```
public static void setInputTextLayoutColor(final int accent, final int text, TextInputLayout textInputLayout, AppCompatEditText edit) {
    edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            AppCompatEditText editText = (AppCompatEditText) v;
            editText.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            if(hasFocus) editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(accent, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            else editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(text, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    });


    setCursorColor(edit, accent);

    try {
        Field field = textInputLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        int[][] states = new int[][]{
                new int[]{}
        };
        int[] colors = new int[]{
                accent
        };
        ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        field.set(textInputLayout, myList);

        Field fDefaultTextColor = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mDefaultTextColor");
        fDefaultTextColor.setAccessible(true);
        fDefaultTextColor.set(textInputLayout, myList);

        Method method = textInputLayout.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("updateLabelState", boolean.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(textInputLayout, true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem with this method is that A) the hint text is colored immediately to the accent color, it doesn't color to the accent when focus is received B) The `EditText` line starts off with the right color, but when it receives focus, it colorizes to `accent` defined in styles, not the programatically set color.

This is the non-focused picture (in reference to the "Event name" field). Here, the color of "event name" should be gray / white (like the text"):
[image: Non-focused <code>TextInputLayout</code>]

This is the focused picture, here, everything is right except the color of the line, which should be green as well. [image: Focused <code>TextInputLayout</code>]

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to figure out dynamically changing the hint color, but I got the line color to change with a listener:

```
    AppCompatEditText edit = (AppCompatEditText)findViewById(R.id.event_create_name_edit);
    edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            AppCompatEditText edit2 = (AppCompatEditText)v;
            if(hasFocus) edit2.setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(rui.getAccent()));
            else edit2.setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(rui.getText()));
        }
    });
```